# Comunicação com CLP Siemens

Tags: c#, .net

Em breve estarei desenvolvendo uma interface com CLP da Siemens, modelo ET-200A.

Esse é um assunto novo para mim e aí estou com algumas dúvidas.

Alguém já lidou com esse tipo de comunicação?
A comunicação é a mesma para qualquer tipo de CLP da Siemens?
O CLP guarda como a informação dentro dele? Tem um banco de dados?

A ideia é desenvolver em C#, coletar a informação do CLP e persistí-la em um banco de dados SQL. A parte da persistência é bem tranquila para mim.

Não encontrei nada a respeito desse modelo na Web-esfera.

Comment: Olá Daniel,  te aconselho a fazer um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conhecer melhor o site.

Answer (score 3):

Olá, trabalhei bastante tempo com automação industrial e posso te dar um norte.
A comunicação com CLPs pode ser feita utilizando vários meios, um deles é com protocolo OPC ( OLE for Process Control ), a maioria dos CLPs ( Siemens, Rockwell etc) possuem este protocolo, mas existem outras interfaces como RS232. O OPC é um protocolo que facilita a captura de dados, geralmente o fabricante disponibiliza um "server controller' que faz a interface entre sua aplicação e o hardware. Nos CLPs da Rockwell da família Contrologix, quem faz essa interface é o RSLinx, para CLPs siemens existe o STEP 7. Neste "server controller" você mapeia todos os endereços dos CLPs da sua rede a adiciona quais o bits de cada CLP que deseja "compartilhar". Após essa configuração, você deve possuir um componente para a sua linguagem de programação, no meu caso utilizava Delphi com o componente pago [Kassl OPC Client](http://www.kassl.de/opc/delphi.shtml), mas existe também a versão para .NET. Nestes componentes você configura os endereços dos CLPs e os bits que deseja capturar.

O CLP pode armazenar algumas informações, mas são limitadas, por que o hardware possui pouca capacidade de armazenamento, e é programado para executar uma tarefa. Então ele fornece a você as informações em tempo real, basta você capturar essas informações e estruturar no seu banco de dados SQL e gerar histórico se for o caso.
Existe um projeto de software livre muito interessante, o [ScadaBR](http://www.scadabr.com.br/). Este software possui todos os componentes necessários para você já começar a desenvolver o seu sistema de monitoramento com CLPs.

Não há muita informação sobre automação industrial mesmo na internet, é um mercado bastante restrito, mas foi pior no passado.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, agora já tenho uma idéia por onde começar 